# While copying data from API using Azure Data Factory to Azure SQL, I'm only getting first row in table. The API response is Nested JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

While copying data from API using Azure Data Factory to Azure SQL, I'm only getting first row in table. The API response is Nested JSON. I've mapped source and sink as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5u9i.png)

Comment: Please check the Mapping screenshot in the link

Comment: Data factory only can get the fist row of the nested josn, because we only can choose one collection in the mapping.

Comment: Please click the collection and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved by enabling the Collection reference in mapping option in copy activity.

Comment: I already have the `Collection Reference` but it didn't work